# Why output shape is changed after as_graph_def() called?

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph

I was using tensorflow and want to save the graph as pb file. But the shape in the graph was changed after `as_graph_def()` being called. Does anybody know why? Thank you!

```
In [10]: self._inception_graph.get_operation_by_name('ExpandDims').outputs
Out[10]: [<tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, 3) dtype=float32>]

In [11]: output_graph = tf.Graph()

In [12]: with output_graph.as_default():
    ...:     _ = tf.import_graph_def(self._inception_graph.as_graph_def(), name='')
    ...: 

In [13]: output_graph.get_operation_by_name('ExpandDims').outputs
Out[13]: [<tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(1, ?, ?, 3) dtype=float32>]
```

Comment: What version of TensorFlow are you using? If it's not recent, give it a try with a newer one. Shape inference has improved over time, it may be that the shape of that tensor can actually be deduced from the graph (from looking at constant values), but that for some reason TensorFlow can only figure it out when importing the GraphDef.

Comment: I was using tf 1.8